# Force new instances of an app to open on the current monitor

Tags: macos, display, applications

Major downside to my multiple monitor setup - too often I try to open an app, or a new instance of it, and it opens on another monitor on the opposite side of my setup, so I end up spending a lot of time dragging windows around.  Is there a way to force apps to open on the monitor I'm currently focused on?

Comment: I know *exactly* what you’re referring to, but for some reason, I can’t replicate it with my dual monitor setup (iMac and external Dell monitor). If I can get the problem to resurface, I’ll see what I did/can do to solve it.

Comment: Do you have "Displays use Separate Spaces" checked in Preferences > Mission Control?

Comment: @benwiggy Very interesting setting I wasn't aware of, but the issue persists whether the box is unchecked or checked.  And personally I don't like that setting unchecked because I can only use one full-screen app at a time.